# Automation testing by ranorex for more then one action

Tags: android, testing, mobile, automated-tests, ranorex

I'm using Ranorex studio 4 for Android testing. Whenever i start recording it records only one action and if i want to add other action i have to stop and start the recording. by performing  the above stated now when i'm trying to replay what i have recorded it is onle able to check the first action and hence giving result failed. I tried using single action per record but the problem is that how to test when the action to performed needs 2 or more actions before as i'm only accesable to the window i land while starting.

Answer (score 0):

That is strange, I've never seen anything like that, maybe you have a weird Ranorex configuration. Have you asked your question on the Ranorex forum http://www.ranorex.com/forum/ they are pretty good and usually answer your question within a day or so.